# Count the repetition of text in a list using google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've got a list of text suppose from A1 to A{n} like these:

```
Alternative
Ambient
Rock
Metal
ecc..
```

Then I've got a list of text in each cell divided by ";"
So for example in the first cell I've got

`Alternative; Rock; Pop`

I've got a list like these for {n} columns, suppose from C1 to C{n}.
What I need to do is COUNT how many times each text (from A1 to A{n}) is present in each list for each column.

So for example suppose I've got two columns:

```
Alternative; Rock; Pop
Ambient; Rock; Metal
```

What I need to know is that Alternative is present only once, Rock two times and so on and get it from B1 to B{n}.

So what I expect is something like

```
A                 B
Alternative       1
Rock              2
```

A text cannot be repeated twice in the same cell.

I've tried using COUNTIF(SPLIT()) but I came up with no result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you'll need to also use `JOIN` to put your columns together before splitting them, `TRIM` to remove leading and trailing whitespace (so that matching is easier), and `ARRAYFORMULA` to apply `TRIM` to all the results of `SPLIT` (as `TRIM` only works on on a single value.)

Putting it all together, you'd have something like the following in `B1`:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(";", $C$1:$C$2), ";"))), A1)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've tried doing something like: =COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(C1; ";"))); A1:A38) but I always get 0 as result. I also try to watch the result of ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(C1; ";"))) and it fill others cell so I think I have to do COUNTIF on that cell, am I wrong? Maybe an example sheet could be useful tu understand a little bit better what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Hey @Mattia - here's a working example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhXMbCgWwBCr8Wj9l-DpvKPRhwfXUit74Dy6Cd-ROrs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Really don't understand what's going on, copy/paste the same formula but I get ERROR from that. Also try to copy the same data you put in, but still get error

Comment: What's the error message? Do you want to share your sheet?

Comment: Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qtw56tjPgThCWMbyfPvdGcx3U4Ne_V-wibfX8eDryXw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So, you have a formula parse error, which should mean that there is a problem with something like the placement of a parentheses or something similar. Try each piece of the formula separately to make sure that they work, then put them back together.

Comment: Well I found the solution! Still don't understand why but I think it's a sheet options. I've got to use: =COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(";"; $C$2:$C$4); ";"))); A2) (simply sub , with ; for function separator). Thank you

Comment: Oh good. I hadn’t thought about the spreadsheet locale mattering for formulas.